# Hidding sections in wiki

Tags: 2010, wiki

I have some long articles in a sharepoint wiki and would like to hide certain sections until the user clicks on the headline to open the section them. How can this be done?

Comment: Hi and welcome! It is easier to help you out if you add information about what version of SharePoint you are using, and what tools you can use :)

Comment: We are using SharePoint 2010, the Wiki is the basic version that comes with this Sharepoint version. No additional tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by default.

I would look into jQuery to expand or collapse your sections. You can deploy this jQuery code in the page in various ways: custom web part, custom page layout, using site assets, content editor web part, ...

One major drawback of this jQuery approach is that your page content (html) must be 100% uniform and correct. If not your jQuery functionality will break.